# Robot java e programa bloqueando os clicks do mesmo

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um robot bem simples para um jogo. meu codigo:

```
if(e.getKeyChar() == 'e'){

Point p = new Point();
p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
textField1.setText(""+p.x);  
textField2.setText(""+p.y);
}

if(e.getKeyChar() == 's'){
try {
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.delay(3000);         
robot.mouseMove(Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText()));
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   robot.delay(1000); 

   } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

enfim, esse é um trecho do codigo, que se pega a coordenada do mouse, e quando aperta `S`, ele move o mouse e clica. bem simples.

Funciona certinho, porem, dentro do jogo, ele nao funciona. aparentemente, o jogo sabe que está vindo de um "robô" e nao de um usuario, dai bloqueia o comando. Existe outra forma de fazer isso?

Mencionei o programa xpadder, pois ele funciona. ou seja, é possivel realizar de alguma outra forma que funcione?

Comment: oque eu realmente queria saber, era outra forma de fazer isso. nao um programa. entendeu? queria saber como fazer o macro sem usar o robot. @Bacco

Comment: @Bacco me desculpe pelo inconveniente. vê se agora ficou mais claro. :D

Comment: Ficou bem melhor depois da sua edição. E não há necessidade de pedir desculpas, meu comentário foi apenas uma orientação para você aproveitar melhor o site. Não houve inconveniente nenhum de sua parte, muito pelo contrário. Sua boa vontade em editar foi um passo extremamente importante para adequar a questão.

Comment: Há um tempo um colega meu implementou algo parecido para criar um bot em um jogo, até onde eu sei ele precisou do `JNativeHook` porque a classe `Robot` sem limitações. Tem poucas informações no [readme do projeto](https://github.com/Iazzetta/GunzStudio#gunzstudio), mas talvez ajude em algo.